# has_many through how to get intermediate object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models

JobRole JobRoleCompetencies Competencies

```
class JobRole
  has_many :job_role_competencies
  has_many :competencies, :through => :job_role_competencies
end
```

JobRoleCompetencies has additional field - min_rate

When I create new model I assign competencies like `JobRole.new(competency_ids: [1,2])`
and after that I want to assign min 'rate' but when I check `JobRole.new(competency_ids: [1,2]).job_role_competencies`  - nothing there - how can I get(or build) this intermediate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
@job_role = JobRole.new
[1, 2].each do |competency_id|
  @job_role.job_role_competencies.build(:min_rate => min_rate, :competency_id => competency_id)
end
```

Comment: after save you get two records in job_role_competencies - with min_rate and without - thats the main problem

Comment: What is possible - update values in after_create callback but I want assign this values before validation

Comment: Your answer correct. I should hide competency_ids and assign them to some temp variable and perform @job_role.job_role_competencies.build(:min_rate => min_rate, :competency_id => competency_id)  before validation

Comment: I'm glad to know it worked out. Please don't forget to pick the answer as the right one if it solved your problem!